# OpenCV KalmanFilter Python3 won't work

Tags: python, opencv, kalman-filter

I try to make use of Kalman filter of open cv in python. It crashes every time I call the "correct" function.
I think the code here under is self explanatory.

Is it me? OpenCV ? The python bindings (i.e. would it work in C++ ) ?

Any help welcome. 
Dummy code and output are below or [on github](https://github.com/renn0xtek9/horror/blob/master/opencv-python-horror.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np
import cv2, numpy as np
kalman = cv2.KalmanFilter(3,3,3,cv2.CV_64F)     #Declare 3 dynamical         parameter 3 state parameter 3 control parameter
kalman.transitionMatrix=1.0*np.eye(3)           #Transition set to identity only the control and the noise are changing the state
#Dummy measurement matrix,  3 measurement each times !
kalman.measurementMatrix=np.matrix([[1.0,2.2,3.10],
                [1.1,2.2,3.30],
                [1.2,2.4,3.70],
                [1.3,2.430,3.50],
                [1.5,2.50,3.340],
                [1.5,2.60,3.70],
                [1.7,2.0,3.30],
                [1.9,2.30,3.20],
                [1.0,2.40,3.50],
                [1.3,2.60,3.60],
                [1.4,2.20,3.20],
                [1.6,2.0,3.20]])

kalman.measurementNoiseCov=1.1*np.eye(3)
kalman.processNoiseCov=1.2*np.eye(3)
kalman.controlMatrix=1.0*np.eye(3)

uk=np.matrix([[0.0],
    [1.2],
    [1.4]])

print("Now checking")
print("Measurement Matrix")
print(kalman.measurementMatrix)
print("Transition Matrix")
print(kalman.transitionMatrix)
print("MeasurementNoiseCov")
print(kalman.measurementNoiseCov)
print("ProcessNoiseCov")
print(kalman.processNoiseCov)
print("ControlMatrix")
print(kalman.controlMatrix)

print("Now attempted to make use of the underdocumented kalman filter in opencv with python ;)")
predicted=kalman.predict(uk)
print("Predicted:")
print(predicted)
print("Will (try to) correct by feeding directly the predicted to correction")
print("So here OpenCV is telling me that KF can not correct its own prediction even though the KF here has same number of dynamical,state and control parameters ?\n...")
estimated=kalman.correct(predicted)
```

**Output (just the crashing line)**

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (C.type() == type && (((flags&GEMM_3_T) == 0 && C.rows == d_size.height && C.cols == d_size.width) || ((flags&GEMM_3_T) != 0 && C.rows == d_size.width && C.cols == d_size.height))) in gemm, file /io/opencv/modules/core/src/matmul.cpp, line 1588
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./opencvhorror.py", line 46, in <module>
estimated=kalman.correct(predicted)
cv2.error: /io/opencv/modules/core/src/matmul.cpp:1588: error: (-215) C.type() == type && (((flags&GEMM_3_T) == 0 && C.rows == d_size.height && C.cols == d_size.width) || ((flags&GEMM_3_T) != 0 && C.rows == d_size.width && C.cols == d_size.height)) in function gemm
```

Comment: Please include your output, including the full stack trace of the error(s) you are getting.

Comment: Sorry,  I have just edited the question and add the output. Should have done earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Ok my Silly mistake... 
I confused the measurement matrix and measurements ....
Thus The size of the matrix were not correct